# AccessControlException when writing to HDFS from eclipse on windows

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I'm having an exception when I try to write files to HDFS from eclipse. My hadoop cluster is running on Ubuntu server 14 and my eclipse is on windows 7. Here is my sample code:

```
String textToWrite = "Hello HDFS! Elephants are awesome!\n";
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(textToWrite.getBytes()));
Path toHdfs = new Path("/tmp/writeMe.txt");

Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.2.72:8020");
// create file system instance
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
// open output stream
FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(toHdfs);
// copy data
IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, conf);
```

And here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=Arbi, access=WRITE, inode="/tmp":hadoop:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:271)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:257)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:179)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5904)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5886)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:5860)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2362)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2315)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2266)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:542)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:369)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1604)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1465)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1390)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:394)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:390)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:390)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:334)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:887)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:784)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:773)
at dz.lab.hdfs.WriteToFile.main(WriteToFile.java:37)
```

How to solve this issue?